# Where did the Charge TM quests go

Tags: pokemon-go

There used to be a research quest that rewarded you with a Charge TM.  I haven't seen these in a few months though.  Did Niantic remove this reward?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The field research quests and their rewards are rotated in monthly intervals. Charged TMs were rewards you could obtain when this feature was initially rolled out, but were not added back into the rotation for quite some time.

During events in March 2019, TMs were added back into the pool of rewards that can be obtained by completing field research quests. The next rotation may remove them yet again, but it shows that TMs were not permanently removed as rewards

**Sources**

- [Eurogamer](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2018-08-02-pokemon-go-field-research-special-research-quests-research-breakthroughs-5392)
- Personal experience